# Lo and MacKinlay variance ratio test in R

Tags: r

I need to conduct the Lo and MacKinlay variance ratio test on a series of returns but I am struggling to understand the code Lo.Mac(r,kvec).

I understand 'r' is the series of returns, but what exactly must the form of 'kvec' be? I read that kvec is the vector of holding periods, so should this be a vector of dates? The example provided by the R helpsheet defines it as `kvec <- c(2,5,10)`, and produces a result table such as:

`k=2  M1=3.39  M2=2.12,...` with numbers attached next to each `k=2,k=5,k=10`

What exactly do these k's mean in this case? and how do we interpret these numbers under M1 and M2?

I defined kvec as a vector of dates in the form of 'Jan 1926, Feb 1926...' but get the error:

```
"Error in filter(y, rep(1, k), method = "convolution") : 
  'filter' is longer than time series"
```

Any help and guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Think of k as k-th lag of your time series (eg. k=1 is the first difference of the time series, k=2 is the 2nd and so on). Lo.Mac is a variance ratio test, meaning it checks whether the VR = 1 for a given k to see whether the series is a random walk (which is the null hypothesis). But when you perform a test like Lo.Mac, it is customary to check the the VR for several lags instead of one. Therefore you need to test for multiple k periods. So you need to specify a vector of lags as numbers not as dates.

M1 is the Lo.Mac statistic under the homoscedastic assumption. M2 is the Lo.Mac statistic under the heteroscedastic assumption. Better to look at M2 than M1 as M2 is based on a more realistic assumption.

M1 and M2 are assumed to follow a normal distribution. So if M1 or M2 is greater than 1.96, you can reject the null hypothesis at 5% significant level.